# Linux capabilities (setcap) seems to disable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, linux-capabilities

I use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to set the path of a certain user library for an application. But if I set capabilities on this application

```
sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=eip myapplication
```

then `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` seems to be ignored. When I launch the program, Linux complains that it cannot find a certain shared library.

I guess that there's some kind of protection kicking in, to prevent applications with extended rights from being hijacked. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's disabled for security reasons.

Answer (score 14):

As already stated in other answers, this behavior is intended. There is some kind of workaround if you can compile (or at least link) the application yourself. Then you can pass `-Wl,-rpath <yourDynamicLibraryPath>` to gcc or `-rpath <yourDynamicLibraryPath>` to ld and you won't have to specify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all on execution.

Comment: Even with -rpath Linux prevents loading shared libraries after calling setcap.

Answer (score 13):

The solution to this problem on linux is as follows:

go to directory 
    `$cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d/`
create a new file 
    $touch xyz.conf 
open this file using any editor
    `$vi xyz.conf`

Add the your dynamic library path in this file line by line for e.g. if your path is as follows:

`/home/xyz/libs1:/home/xyz/libs2/:/home/xyz/libs3/`
then there should be three entries in this file as follows:
`/home/xyz/libs1/`
`/home/xyz/libs2/`
`/home/xyz/libs3/`

Then save this file and execute the following command:
    `$ldconfig`

All the above mentioned operation need to be performed from root login

Comment: And yum will be broken.

Answer (score 9):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) for `sudo` explains:

> Note that the dynamic linker on most operating systems will remove
>   variables that can control dynamic linking from the environment of
>   setuid executables, including sudo.  Depending on the operating system
>   this may include *RLD*, DYLD**, LD_*, LDR_*, LIBPATH, SHLIB_PATH, and
>   others.  These type of variables are removed from the environment
>   before sudo even begins execution and, as such, it is not possible for
>   sudo to preserve them.

As [this link explains](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/dlls.html), the actual mechanism for doing this is in glibc. If the UID does not match the EUID (which is the case for any `setuid` program, including `sudo`), then all "unsecure environment variables" are removed. Thus, a program with elevated privileges runs without alteration.

Comment: This is all very well, but setcap doesn't change UID or EUID. It does add capabilities ("elevated permissions").

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to consider is to "correct" a poorly compiled ELF shared library and/or executable using patchelf to set the rpath.
https://nixos.org/patchelf.html

ld.so.conf is not always the sure bet.  It will work if whatever you are running was compiled properly.  In my case, with a particular specially packaged vendor's apache product, it was compiled so poorly:  They did not even use unique .so filenames so they conflicted with .so filenames from RPMs in the base RHEL repositories that provided some pretty critical commonly used libraries. So this was the only option to isolate how they were used.  Using ld.so.conf against those shared objects in the vendor's lib path would have blown away a lot of stuff, that included yum, along with glibc shared library failures, system-wide.

Comment: note that you'll have to rerun your setcap commands on the edited binary.    Notwithstanding that, this is the most useful answer here - especially if a vendor has a misconfigured build pipeline