# scapy: Operation not permitted when sending packets

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to learn a bit of packet generation with scapy. It looks pretty cool. Following some documentation I'm doing this:

```
l3=IP(dst="192.168.0.1", src="192.168.0.2", tos=(46 << 2))
```

But only to get the error message of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 251, in send
    __gen_send(conf.L3socket(*args, **kargs), x, inter=inter, loop=loop, count=count,verbose=verbose, realtime=realtime)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 307, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(type))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Running scapy as root solved the problem. But that's not what I wanted. Is it because normal user can't create RAW socket? If so, is there a solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scapy needs root privileges to create raw sockets because it uses the Python socket library. Raw sockets are only allowed to used "with an effective user ID of 0 or the CAP_NET_RAW capability" according to the [Linux raw man pages.](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw)

I can't find what looks to be reliable documentation on setting the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability, but if you are looking to a work around to running Scapy scripts that user raw sockets without root, that is what you need to do.

Comment: Let me know if you successfully do this using the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability.

Answer (score 8):

To run Scapy with just `cap_net_raw` privilege...

The safest and less complicated way I know is, in order:

1. Make a personal copy of the python binary:

   $ sudo cp /usr/bin/python2.7 ~/python_netraw
2. Own it:

   $ sudo chown `your user name` ~/python_netraw
3. Don't let anybody else run it:

   $ chmod -x,u+x ~/python_netraw
4. Give it cap_net_raw capability:

   $ sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip /usr/bin/python_netraw
5. Run scapy with it:

   $ ~/python_netraw -O /usr/bin/scapy

(Or use `sudo` each time you need to run Scapy with raw privileges.)

Answer (score 5):

A dirty approach, possibly insecure: Directly give CAP_NET_RAW capability to Python:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw=eip $(readlink -f $(which python))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the other answers also suggest setting CAP_NET_RAW.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I propose to do it for the global executable. However, this gives every user script the capability to create raw sockets.

Comment: Also: Shared libraries cannot be directly included anymore, because the LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets disabled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843178/linux-capabilities-setcap-seems-to-disable-ld-library-path

Answer (score 0):

To run a temporary python environment (like for scapy) with cap_net_raw I found this works:

```
sudo -E capsh --caps="cap_setpcap,cap_setuid,cap_setgid+ep cap_net_raw+eip" --keep=1 --user="$USER" --addamb="cap_net_raw" -- -c /usr/bin/python3
```

adapted from the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Capabilities#Running_a_program_with_temporary_capabilities)

Answer (score 0):

I did't try it by myself yet but I guess this could be an option (it's from scapy tutorial "Scapy in 15 minutes"):

> Alternatively, Scapy can use OS sockets to send and receive packets.
> The following example assigns an UDP socket to a Scapy StreamSocket,
> which is then used to query [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) IPv4 address. Unlike other
> Scapy sockets, **StreamSockets do not require root privileges**.

```
import socket

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # create an UDP socket
sck.connect(("8.8.8.8", 53))  # connect to 8.8.8.8 on 53/UDP

# Create the StreamSocket and gives the class used to decode the answer
ssck = StreamSocket(sck)
ssck.basecls = DNS

# Send the DNS query
ssck.sr1(DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="www.example.com")))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, the above example will not work for data-link layer sockets