# Start / stop CAN boards from userspace using libsocketcan

Tags: c++, linux, can-bus, userspace, socketcan

I am trying to start / stop CAN boards or to update their baudrate using SocketCAN from userspace. My tests are performed on PeakSystem and IXXAT USB-to-CAN V1/V2 boards.

My first attempt was to use visudo and to enable NOPASSWD to "ip link set ...", and then to call "sudo ip link set ..." in my C++ code.
Complete visudo line is:

```
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/ip link set can[0123456789]* type can bitrate [0123456789]*, /bin/ip link set can[0123456789]* up, /bin/ip link set can[0123456789]* down
```

Then, I tried with Linux capabilities by adding capabilities to /bin/ip. That allows me to call "ip link set ..." from my C++ code which was even better.
Add capabilities command:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+ep /bin/ip
```

But then I discovered [libsocketcan](http://git.pengutronix.de/?p=tools/libsocketcan.git) which is a far better approach than calling command lines from C++. However when calling "can_set_bitrate" or "can_do_start", I have an error "RTNETLINK: Operation not permitted". But things are working fine when my program is launched as root. Other functions like can_get_state are working fine in userspace (actually, they are returning : 4 -> CAN_STATE_STOPPED).
I tried to adding capabilities to my program without any success ""sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+ep ./myprogram".

How can I allow my program to use libsocketcan in userspace?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+ep /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsocketcan.so.2.2.1` does not help either... I really don't know how I can make it work.

Comment: `sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+ep /bin/ip` is not working anymore, I cannot call "ip link set ..." from CLI or C++ code without root access anymore. No solution until now. Keep searching...

Answer (score 1):

`sudo setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+ep your_executable` is the solution. You may need to compile with `-Wl,-rpath` so your program finds its shared libraries (also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955480/5559867))

Comment: This did not work for me. I see the same message: "RTNETLINK: Operation not permitted".