# Change the scheduling policy and priority of a thread to real-time

Tags: c, linux, root, scheduling

I'm write a time-critical application in C on an embedded computer and need to change the scheduling policy of the process. Using `pthread_setscheduler` with `SCHED_RR` leads to sufficient results for me. But now the application needs *root*-rights. But giving *root*-rights to the application is not very nice. Is there any possibility to set round-robin without the need of *root*-rights? 
Or there are a more elegant solution?

---

Another approach with `setcap`

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_nice+ep my_application
```

leads to problems while loading some own shared libraries which are placed in several folders.

Comment: Nope. Scheduling policies of OS are not allowed to be modified by non-super users for a reason. Similarly shared libraries (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_PRELOAD etc) don't work for the same reason. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9843178/1275169) for a couple options using which you could make it work with `setcap` -- which requires you to recompile your shared libraries or place them in standard locations. Otherwise, you are out of luck.

Comment: You could set the scheduling policy at startup and then drop root rights.  This is analogous to what many system services do when they need to obtain access to protected resources, such as reserved network ports, but do not need to operate with continuing privilege.

Comment: What about using `fakeroot`? Is this an appropriate way?