# Java "symbol lookup error" for JLI_InitArgProcessing when running with setcap capabilities

Tags: java, unix, permissions, packet-capture, linux-capabilities

We installed Java 11 on a server that is meant to monitor a network interface for traffic.

After the initial installation (`yum install java-11-openjdk-devel.x86_64`) the `java` command works properly for both **root** and a **regular user.**

However, our Java application will not be running as root. We then ran:

```
setcap cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin=eip /path/to/java
```

It sets the capabilities, and running `java -version` as **root** works fine.

**But after running setcap**, when I try to run `java -version` as a regular user, I see:

```
java: symbol lookup error: java: undefined symbol: JLI_InitArgProcessing
```

This seems to be an intended security protection as discussed here: [Linux capabilities (setcap) seems to disable LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843178/linux-capabilities-setcap-seems-to-disable-ld-library-path)

**But my question is:** How can I allow `java` to use these capabilities (network packet capture) under a regular user account?

*Note:* Unsetting the capabilities via `setcap -r /path/to/java` allows a regular user to run `java` again - so the issue is isolated to capabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding this file:

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf
```

With the single-line contents:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.1.13-3.0.1.el7_6.x86_64/lib/jli
```

And rebooting the server.

*Obviously, that directory path should point to your specific JDK*

Comment: Instead of rebooting, you might be able to do `sudo ldconfig` to rebuild the cache. If you're debugging or running the Java app inside Eclipse, run the ldconfig command and restart Eclipse. This seems to work for me.

Comment: Does it work if I have more than 1 JVM, e.g. 8 and 11? It looks as if the first line wins.

Comment: @DavidRiccitelli Good question, I have no idea.