# java13 and Eclipse strange behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, java-13, eclipse-2019-09

I'm trying to use Java 13 with Eclipse on Linux.
I'm trying to create a 'portable' java+eclipse folder, that can be moved between machines.
I have downloaded and unzipped
Java 13 from
  https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html

Eclipse from 
  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.13RC1-201908281800/eclipse-SDK-4.13RC1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

and inside the eclipse market place I have installed all the parts of
  https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.13-P-builds

I have set the jdk to the jdk13 folder.
The result is that Eclipse can compile my Java13 code, but
not run it.
When I try to run I get

```
[..]/EclipseJava13/jdk-13/bin/java: symbol lookup error: [..]/EclipseJava13/jdk-13/bin/java: undefined symbol: JLI_InitArgProcessing
```

I can compile and run Java13 from command line no problem using commands:

```
../../../jdk-13/bin/javac --release 13 --enable-preview main/Main.java
../../../jdk-13/bin/java --enable-preview main.Main
```

If I cut-paste the *.class generated by eclipse I can run them using command

```
../../../jdk-13/bin/java --enable-preview main.Main
```

no problem. Thus Eclipse is recognizing Java 13 and is correctly compiling Java 13 code.

But... when I try to run from inside Eclipse, I get that error.
I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: You can check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675535/java-symbol-lookup-error-for-jli-initargprocessing-when-running-with-setcap-ca

Comment: Please show the command line that is used by Eclipse: in the run configuration there is a _Show Command Line_ button for that.

Comment: Note that you have installed the RC1 version of 2019-09 (4.13). There was a RC2 and RC2a release after that - the final release is on https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.13-201909161045/

Comment: Here is the show command line output:
/[..]/EclipseJava13/jdk-13/bin/java -ea --enable-preview -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p /[..]/EclipseJava13/workspaceTest/TestSwitch/bin --enable-preview -m testSwitch/main.Main

Of course, I tried to 'run' this exact line from the console, and... IT WORKS NO PROBLEM. somehow eclipse runs Java in an environment with different privileges

Comment: I have also reinstalled eclipse using the suggestion of greg, but there is no change at all.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have discovered the issue.
Eclipse itself is a Java program.
On my machine I also had Java8
eclipse was running using Java8.
Java8 was pre-loading a version of the library containing symbol JLI_InitArgProcessing in the environment. Thus when Java 13 was run in the same environment it was trying to reuse the cached version of such library.
If I start eclipse using Java13, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to add `--release 13` with "[Java 13 Support for Eclipse 2019-09](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-13-support-eclipse-2019-09-413)"

It refers to [Eclipse R-4.13-201909161045/](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.13-201909161045/), which does have official [Java support](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.13/jdt.php#Java_13)

> The release notably includes the following Java 13 features:
>
> - [JEP 354: Switch Expressions (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/354).
> - [JEP 355: Text Blocks (Preview)](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355).

See "[Wiki Java13/Examples](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java13/Examples)".

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/9/9b/FileAddJ13.png]

Comment: A minor clarification re _"You should not need to add --release 13"_: it's actually more severe than that. You absolutely must not add **--release 13** to _Default VM Arguments_. If you do you will get the error `"Unrecognized option: --release"` in the Console window, and your Java 13 application won't run. Java 13 preview features work just fine without anything specified in _Default VM Arguments_.

Comment: I'm very confused about this answer: from command line I need to add either 
--release 13 --enable-preview 
or
-source 13 --enable-preview 
to make it compile. Anyway, my problem is on running it, compilation goes fine.

Comment: @MarcoServetto This answer was to say that by using the newly released Eclipse R-4.13-201909161045/, you would not need to add any 13 option, because by default that would be compatible with Java 13. Officially. Not "as a preview". But I see you have found a PATH issue.